# ld: library not found for -lrt

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, apache-kafka

I am trying to run a project that was made and works for Ubuntu but on Mac OS. And when I am doing the make I got the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lrt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [consumer] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/consumer.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can't see any library with that name at thole project.

Can anyone explain what it is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On old Linux systems, several functions, such as [`clock_gettime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), are documented to need `-lrt` for *old* versions of GNU libc. This is no more the case on *recent* [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (after 2.17 from 2013).

So you can  remove `-lrt`  from your `Makefile` (and remove the thing from your `cmake` configuration  thing generating it).

BTW, removing `-lrt` should also fit for *recent* Linux distributions.

PS. If you are paying support for your Linux system, you should ask your support for advice.

Comment: It’s a shame that these “old” Linux systems are still some of the most commonly used and most commercially relevant, namely RHEL 7 and CentOS 7. So, for the time being, we can’t just purge `-lrt` from our build systems.

Comment: If you buy support from RedHat, you need to ask them.

Comment: I’m not, but I support customers who are. As for “asking” them, the answer is that there’s no solution except to compile against glibc 2.17 (or to ship an alternative glibc, with all the pain that entails). RHEL 7 and CentOS 7 ship with 2.17 until end of life by design.