# Shared Memory Library -lrt in C on macOS

Tags: c, macos, shared-memory

I'm doing a university assignment on shared memory on C, I need to use the functions `shm_open()`, `mmap()`, `ftruncate()`, `shm_unlink()`, etc. using a Mac with macOS Mojave 10.14
My teacher told me I need to use the `-lrt` library in my Makefile to make it work but when I "make" I got an error which goes

```
ld: library not found for -lrt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Is the library spelled work? If I don't have it, I need to download it? Do I even need a specific library? ('cause on the internet I didn't find anybody using one...) 
I'm very confused.

Comment: You only need `-lrt` on (some versions of) Linux. Your code should link OK without it on macOS.

Comment: I supposed it was something about the OS, I just deleted the library and now it's working. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ld: library not found for -lrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703239/ld-library-not-found-for-lrt)