# library not found for -lrt

Tags: c, macos, gcc, makefile, macos-mojave

I am compiling a Makefile that needs -lrt library. My compiler is gcc-8 and I am currently working on a OSX Mojave OS. 
I run from terminal using the make command, and I get the following error:

> ld: library not found for -lrt
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [eflomal] Error 1

I have already tried to remove -lrt from LDFLAGS but in that case I get other errors:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/gcc-8 -lm -lgomp -fopenmp  eflomal.o   -o eflomal
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___kmpc_critical", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..57 in eflomal.o
      _.omp_outlined..61 in eflomal.o
  "___kmpc_end_critical", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..57 in eflomal.o
      _.omp_outlined..61 in eflomal.o
  "___kmpc_for_static_fini", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in eflomal.o
      _.omp_outlined..57 in eflomal.o
      _.omp_outlined..61 in eflomal.o
  "___kmpc_for_static_init_4", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in eflomal.o
      _.omp_outlined..57 in eflomal.o
      _.omp_outlined..61 in eflomal.o
  "___kmpc_fork_call", referenced from:
      _main in eflomal.o
      _align in eflomal.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The Makefile header is the following:

```
export CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/g++-8
export CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/gcc-8
CFLAGS=-Ofast -march=native -Wall --std=gnu99 -Wno-unused-function -g -fopenmp
# This is more suitable for debugging:
#CFLAGS=-Og -Wall --std=gnu99 -Wno-unused-function -g -fopenmp
#LDFLAGS=-lm -lrt -lgomp -fopenmp
LDFLAGS=-lm -lgomp -fopenmp -lrt
```

The first two lines are needed to use gcc compiler instead of clang (default on OSX).

Any idea on how to fix the problem?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595529/shared-memory-library-lrt-in-c-on-macos) suggests just to remove it from the Makefile. What "other errors" do you get when you do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ld: library not found for -lrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703239/ld-library-not-found-for-lrt)

Comment: When I remore -lrt from LDFLAGS  I get the following error '''ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64'''

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this, in more detail (which symbols?)

Comment: Done. Hope that the edit could help in better understanding the issue.

Comment: Googling `__kmpc_critical` suggests it may be unrelated...?

Comment: The link order is wrong. The `-lm -lgomp` needs to be at the end of the link line in order to resolve the dependency correctly. In a typical makefile, this means putting them in the `LDLIBS` variable, not in the `LDFLAGS` variable. i.e. in the makefile do: `LDLIBS += -lm -lgomp` and it *should* work.

Comment: Solved: I run "make clear" and then "make" having removed -lrt from makefile. It correctly built everything.